# How can I detect wrapping with javascript?

Tags: javascript, word-wrap

I have a load of fixed width divs inside a dynamic width div. The fixed divs all go next to each other and eventually wrap. What I want is to detect if one div ends up on a line on it's own. The only way I can think of for doing this is detecting where the divs wrap but I haven't been able to figure out how. Help is really appreciated.

Comment: Providing an exemple would somehow help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

so you want to know if the div is on it's own row?

you can check each div's [offsetTop](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) to check against the other div's if they are on the same row. if the div's offsetTop dont match any of the others, then it's on it's own.