# How to set full width to multi-row dynamic floating elements

Tags: css, css-float

I have a container that has a variable number of child elements, which are dynamically created which need to be next to each other and fit the entire width of its parents. This sounds pretty straightforward, but I'm unable to make the child take the full width of the container.

Here's a more visual example:

Use case 1: Perfect width scenario

```
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
c1111 c222222222 c333 c4444444444 c555555
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
```

Use case 2: New child have been added and some now has a diffenrent width

```
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
c1111 c222222 c333 c4444444444
c55555555555555 c6666
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
```

I would like the remaining space to be adjusted. The way I've got so far is by doing something like this:

```
.p {
    display: table;
}
.c {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
```

Desired behavior:

```
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
c1111 c222222 c333 c4444444444(444444444)
c55555555555555 c6666(666666666666666666)
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
```

Notice how the extra space have been filled by the last child on each row (in parens). Is this possible with pure CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle so we can see issue in live..thank you

Comment: No, this is not possible with any standard layout method, **including flexbox**. You would need javascript.

Comment: Flexbox can get *close* but only by expanding each child so that rows are filled - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/eZKqdr There is no CSS method to selecting the last child of a 'row' that only appears when wrapping occurs.

Comment: @Paulie_D this is exactly what I want! unfortunately we still support our beloved IE, so flexbox is not an option. So looks like Javascript is the way to go. thanks!

Comment: Depends on which version of IE. Flexbox is supported by IE10/11/Edge

Comment: not really related to CSS, but thought I'd try asking :) do you know of a way in Javascript to get the last child of each row? (when wrapping occurs) thanks!x

Comment: You have to do some weird math comparing the position value of each element to the edge/top of the viewport etc and then do something if it's more than a specific number. Try an SO search for "javascript detect wrapping" or similar? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838202/how-can-i-detect-wrapping-with-javascript